# Зачем кэширование при autoboxing

Tags: java, информатика, history

Не могу понять зачем в java существует специальный массив в классе-обертке, допустим **Integer**, где хранятся объекты-обертки  для примитивов: от -128 до 127. Почему не создается новый объект-обертка для этого диапазона, как с остальными примитивами? Так ли сильно этот массив оптимизирует программу? И почему диапазон 8 байт, ни больше ни меньше? Если кто-то хорошо знаком с историей языка, прошу объясните такое решение.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Кстати, в питоне тоже небольшие числа закэшированы, только там в диапазоне `[-5; 256]`. Но в питоне то точно создание объектов сильно тормозит, не знаю как в `Java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Это кэширование появилось с Java 5.
2. Нет лишнего создания объекта - это ускоряет работу, уменьшает расходы памяти и нагрузку на GC (сборщик мусора).
3. Например, с Java 9 создание `Integer` через конструктор (`new`) является deprecated (поскольку всегда создаёт обёртку), нужно применять `valueOf`, который как раз использует кэширование при попадании числа в диапазон.
4. Есть опция (если правильно помню, с Java 7) `-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=size`, которая позволяет изменить диапазон кэшируемых значений.
5. В спецификацию языка были явно внесены диапазоны:

> If the value p being boxed is true, false, a byte, a char in the range \u0000 to \u007f, or an int or short number between -128 and 127, then let r1 and r2 be the results of any two boxing conversions of p. It is always the case that r1 == r2.

Это достигается только при условии, что возвращаются одни и те же экземпляры объектов. Что и достигается кэшированием.